# How to make sure an integer is divisible by another integer

Tags: javascript

**Scenario**

I have a reservation form for rooms.

All below fields are integers

`roomsneeded`(total room needed.. calculated based on maxguest)

`maxguest`(maximum guest allowed per room)

`checkin_guest_count`(Total number of people that needs room)

So as the `maxguest increases/decreases` I need to `increase/decrease` the `roomsneeded`.

So by keeping above in mind lets make an `example`

Lets say `maxguest=3` and `checkin_guest_count=17`..So how can I calculate `roomsneeded`?

Is `modulus` useful here as I am not looking for `exact divisibles`?

> I am trying to achieve this on `javascript`(but looking for the basic
>   idea on the math needed)

Comment: `function roomsneeded(maxguest, checkin_guest_count) { return Math.ceil(checkin_guest_count / maxguest) }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than checking that the numbers are exactly divisible - assuming that you can have fewer than the maximum number of occupants in a room - simply use `Math.ceil()`:

```
var roomsNeeded = Math.ceil( checkin_guest_count / maxguest );
// 17 / 3 => 5.6...
// Math.ceil( 17 / 3 ) => 6
```

Proof of concept below:

```js
function calculate() {

  // retrieving the various values required for the
  // calculation:
  var checkin_guest_count = document.getElementById('checkin_guest_count').value,
    maxguest = document.getElementById('maxguest').value,
    result = document.getElementById('result'),

    // dividing the number of guests by the maximum 
    // number of guests per room, and then rounding
    // that value up to the nearest integer (eg
    // Math.ceil(5.1) will return 6):
    numRooms = Math.ceil(checkin_guest_count / maxguest);

  // here we update the value of the 'result' node
  // to either the numRooms value (if numRooms is a
  // finite number, so we haven't tried to divide by
  //  zero) or to 0 if the numRooms is infinite:
  result.value = Number.isFinite(numRooms) ? numRooms : 0;
  return numRooms;
}

// retrieving the collection of <input> elements whose
// type attribute is 'number', and converting that collection
// to an Array (using Array.from()):
var inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type = number]'));

// iterating over the Array using Array.prototype.forEach():
inputs.forEach(function(input) {

  // binding the named function calcuate() (note the lack of
  // parentheses in the event-binding) as the event-handler
  // for the 'change' event:
  input.addEventListener('change', calculate);
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0.2em 0;
}
label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}
label span::after {
  content: ': ';
}
label span + input {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<label><span>Number of guests</span>
  <input type="number" id="checkin_guest_count" step="1" />
</label>

<label><span>Maximum guests per room</span>
  <input type="number" id="maxguest" step="1" min="1" />
</label>

<label><span>Number of rooms</span>
  <input type="number" id="result" readonly />
</label>
```

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil).
- [`Number.isFinite()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of some help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
roomsneeded = Math.cell(checkin_guest_count / maxguest);
```

> Math.ceil() rounds a number up to the nearest integer

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to achieve this on javascript(but looking for the basic
>   idea on the math needed)

So basically your rooms needed will always be:

```
var rooms_needed = Math.ceil(checkin_guest_count/maxguest);
```

Any more guests than the maximum capacity should be given another room.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
var maxguest = 3; //magic number?
var checkin_guest_count = 17; //magic number?

function roomsneeded(maxGuest, checkinGuestCount) {
    if (maxGuest > 0) { // Dividing by zero creates black holes
        return Math.ceil(checkinGuestCount / maxGuest); //Math.ceil => round to highest int
    } else return 0;
}
alert(roomsneeded(maxguest, checkin_guest_count));
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer division should give you 17/3=5. Then if 17 mod 3 is greater than 0, one more room is needed (5+1).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For code examples, you can use the code block to enclose your code. It'll be more helpful to the questioner and anyone else reading it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if one integer is divisible by another using this scheme:

```
if( !(int1 % int2) ) {
 /* Your cool code here */
}
```

You dont need anything else

Answer (score 0):

If people's preference that they want an individual room for themselves vs they can share room with someone else doesn't count then you can fill each room with the maximum number of people it can accommodate and this means that the total number of rooms you have multiplied by the maximum guests allowed per room should be equal to the total number of guests.

`rooms * max_guests = total_guests`

Which implies

`rooms = total_guests/max_guests`

Since then number of rooms can't be fractional you will have to take the ceiling of that.

If each guest can have a preference like they want to stay alone then you have to take the worst case scenario which implies that the total number of rooms is equal to the number of guests.

`rooms = total_guests`

Note: Modulus gives the residue after division, you can use modulus to indicate whether to add 1 to the quotient that remains after division in method 1.

That is if `total_guests % max_guests != 0` then add 1 to the total rooms.